# InvokeMethod doesn't work with SLOT(...), but works with conts char *

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have the next classes: `FoxCom` and `FoxComCircle`. In `FoxCom` I have the next code:

```
...
public slots:
 void bytesWrite(QByteArray bytes, qint32 requestedTimeout = -1);
...
FoxComCircle * circle;
...

void FoxCom::bytesWrite(QByteArray bytes, qint32 requestedTimeout)
{
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(circle,
                              //SLOT(bytesToWrite(QByteArray,qint32)),
                              "bytesToWrite",
                              Qt::QueuedConnection,
                              Q_ARG(QByteArray, bytes),
                              Q_ARG(qint32, requestedTimeout));
}
```

And in `FoxComCircle`:

```
...
public slots:
  void bytesToWrite(QByteArray bytes, qint32 requestedTimeout);
...
void FoxComCircle::bytesToWrite(QByteArray bytes, qint32 requestedTimeout)
{
   //some stinky code here
}
```

And there is the next behaviour: when I comment `"bytesToWrite",` and use `SLOT(bytesToWrite(QByteArray,qint32)),` I have the next message in the output console when `FoxCom::bytesWrite` is called:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method FoxComCircle::1bytesToWrite(QByteArray
```

,qint32)(QByteArray,qint32)

But when I use the const char * name directly (as shown in the code above) it works.

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. `FoxCom` and `FoxComCircle` are in different threads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` description in Qt documentation:

> Invokes the member (a signal or a slot **name**) on the object obj...

Thus, you have to provide the **name** of the slot, and not the complete signature. This is consistent, because you provide slot's arguments as the following arguments of `invokeMethod` function.

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't it strange that usually Qt uses standardised calls, but not now?

Comment: @AlexTiger, what do you mean? SLOT and SIGNAL should be used in QObject::connect() function, and documentation explicitly mentions that, however this is not a case for invokeMethod.